# MySQL: Get record where TIME('xx:yy:zz') between start and end time

Tags: php, mysql

This is the table:

```
+----+-----------+------------+----------+
| id | id_sensor | start_time | end_time |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+
|  1 |        12 | 21:15:00   | 02:45:00 |
|  2 |         7 | 00:00:00   | 23:15:00 |
|  3 |         5 | 04:30:00   | 16:30:00 |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+
```

I need to get record(s) where a specific time (e.g. 01:00:00) passed by PHP is between. start_time and end_time are TIME fields in UTC, I'm passing to the query hour via php, note, converted in php from user_timezone to UTC.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE TIME('01:00:00') BETWEEN start_time AND end_time;
```

Query returns only record id 2, not the 1. I need both, in this case (for id 1, end time ofcourse is next day).

Of course, if we looking for TIME('01:00:00'), we **don't** need the id 3.

Thank you.

Comment: And what's the logic to figure out that the range wraps the day? Because if you don't have also a date field then every start time/end time couple will match your query, one way or the other :D

Comment: @Johhny that was my expected behaviour. But, if you try my SQL, it doesn't get the id 1....

Comment: You don't understand my comment. Extend your question with a line that you do NOT want returned.

Comment: @Johnny just done!

Comment: now I understand your question, yes I would go with proposed answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the logic you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE (start_time < end_time AND TIME('01:00:00') BETWEEN start_time AND end_time) OR
      (start_time > end_time AND TIME('01:00:00') NOT BETWEEN end_time AND start_time);
```

Comment: Sure, it works! I cannot understand why the NOT BETWEEN works in case of id 1... But Thank you

Comment: This is great, but it will give you false positives, actually it will match all your records where start > end. If `start_time > end_time` the `NOT BETWEEN start_time AND end_time` will be always true, it should be 
`NOT BETWEEN end_time AND start_time`, reverse the times.

Comment: Query for `TIME("05:00:00")` it will match the 3 records but should be only 1 and 3

Comment: Gordon edit your answer and I will accept. Thank you another time to @phobia82

Answer (score -1):

now() returns both, current time and date. You can also work with curtime(), which returns only the current time.

BTW, i think that working with SELECT * should be avoided (maybe you used it just for this example), it is IMHO always better to list the fields needed explicitly.

Comment: I don't / cannot work with NOW(). Thank you for your SELECT *, I know, It's only a test... thank you